# В адресной строке только буквы, цифры,  "-" и "." и ссылка завершалась на .html

Tags: регулярные-выражения, безопасность

Hужнo такой скрипт либо регулярное выражение, чтобы в адресной строке были только латинские  буквы, цифры, знак тире и знак точка, а ссылка завершалась на `.html`. Примерно так:

```
test500.ru/html5.html 
test500.ru/html-osnovi.html  test500.ru/html-osno5vi.html.
```

У меня получается удалять знаки `" \', $,@ ,^,(,), {}"`, a вот со знаками `" ",<,>|  "` не справляюсь.

Comment: @vasak, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Господи, ну ей-богу, в чем проблема не ставить пробел перед запятой и знать, как пишется слово "окончалась"?

Вот ваша регулярка соответствия

```
^[a-zA-Z\d\-\./]+\.html$
```

Вот регулярка замены всего лишнего

```
([^a-zA-Z\d\-\./]+) // суффикс .html ни одним символом не входит в класс, и поэтому должен сохраниться.
```

протокол (`http://`) и хост в регулярку не включаются.